# Physical memory mapping in a device driver

Tags: linux, memory

I have a device who has memory setting at a physical address and I need to get access to it.  I also don't have the use of "open" so I can't open the "/dev/mem" file, sadly.

Looking around, it appears as though "vm_insert_page()" may be what I need to use but I'm not sure.  My device memory (a PRU sitting inside of the am335x processor) sits at address 0x4a30.0000.

I can't seem to find any useful examples on how to do this on the web.  Can anyone give me a clue?

Thank you!

Comment: A hint 
[Linux Device Drivers - free book rev2 @xml](http://www.xml.com/ldd/chapter/book/ch08.html#t4), chapter 8 "HW management", using IO Memory. 
[Linux Device Drivers - free book rev3 @LWN](https://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/) chapters 9 and 15
It's rather short but invaluable read.

Comment: Thanks, JustMe.   My ultimate solution was to use ioremap() which did the trick just fine.